How am i supposed to solve this error when tackling a multiple chat session code in flask?
I am building a chatbot using flask. I've been on this problem for nearly a week and I can't seem to figure it out.
As you can see, the chat() and chat_session() functions are both the same code, but one includes the sessions.
The problem is that, while everything works fine (in both 'POST' and 'GET' methods) in chat() even storing and retrieving in/from the db (i use MongoDB), the whole 'POST' method in chat_session() doesn't work.
I want the user_input and bot_response in each session stored with their respective session_id in the db, so that i could retrieve them.
But the storing doesn't work, so the retrieval doesn't work, so that makes the chat sessions useless.
chat_messages_collection = db.chat_messages (includes the chat_history [] for the chat() convo)
active_chat_sessions_collection = db.active_chat_sessions (includes active chat sessions)
chat_sessions_collection = db.chat_sessions (includes active chat sessions plus their respective session_history [])
chat_history_collection=db.chat_history (includes the separate user input and bot response for the chat() convo for chat history retrieval and display)
session_history_collection=db.session_history (includes the separate user input and bot response for each session's convo for chat history retrieval and display)
session_messages_collection = db.session_messages (includes the session_history [] for the each session's convo)

This is the code:
`# Function to retrieve conversation history
def get_chat_history():
    return list(chat_history_collection.find())

@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chat():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        chat_history = get_chat_history()
        return render_template('chatbot.html', chat_history=chat_history)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.json['user_input']
        chat_history_collection.insert_one({'sender': 'user', 'message': user_input})
        response = rag_chain.invoke(user_input)
        bot_response = response.split('answer: ')[1].strip()
        chat_history_collection.insert_one({'sender': 'bot', 'message': bot_response})

        # Retrieve the last document if any exists
        last_chat_document = chat_messages_collection.find_one(sort=[('_id', -1)])
        
        # Check if a document exists and extract the existing chat history
        if last_chat_document:
            chat_history = last_chat_document.get('chat_history', [])
        else:
            chat_history = []
        
        # Append the current user input and bot response to the chat history
        chat_history.append({'user_input': user_input, 'bot_response': bot_response})
        
        # Update the chat history in the database
        if last_chat_document:
            chat_messages_collection.update_one({'_id': last_chat_document['_id']}, {'$set': {'chat_history': chat_history}})
        else:
            chat_messages_collection.insert_one({'chat_history': chat_history})
        
        # Format the chat history
        formatted_chat_history = []
        for entry in chat_history:
            formatted_entry = {
                'user_input': entry['user_input'],
                'bot_response': entry['bot_response']
            }
            formatted_chat_history.append(formatted_entry)
        return response

@app.route('/start_new_chat_session', methods=['POST'])
def start_new_chat_session():
    # Generate a session ID
    session_id = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    
    # Store the session ID in the active chat sessions collection
    active_chat_sessions_collection.insert_one({'session_id': session_id})
    
    # Store an empty chat history for the session
    chat_sessions_collection.insert_one({'session_id': session_id, 'session_history': []})
    
    # Return the session ID to the client
    return jsonify({'success': True, 'sessionId': session_id})

@app.route('/get_chat_sessions', methods=['GET'])
def get_chat_sessions():
    # Retrieve existing chat sessions from the active chat sessions collection
    sessions = list(active_chat_sessions_collection.find({}, {'_id': 0, 'session_id': 1}))
    
    session_ids = [session['session_id'] for session in sessions]

    # Return the list of session IDs to the client
    return jsonify({'success': True, 'sessions': session_ids})

@app.route('/chat/<int:session_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chat_session(session_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Retrieve chat history for the specified session ID
        session_history = get_session_history(session_id)
        return render_template('chat.html', session_history=session_history, session_id=session_id)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        user_input = request.json['user_input']
        session_messages_collection.insert_one({'session_id': session_id, 'sender': 'user', 'message': user_input})
        response = rag_chain.invoke(user_input)
        bot_response = response.split('answer: ')[1].strip()
        session_messages_collection.insert_one({'session_id': session_id, 'sender': 'bot', 'message': bot_response})
        # Update session history
        update_session_history(session_id, user_input, bot_response)
        return jsonify({'response': bot_response, 'success': True, 'session_id': session_id})

def get_session_history(session_id):
    # Retrieve chat history for the specified session ID from the session_history collection
    session_history = session_history_collection.find_one({'session_id': session_id})
    return session_history.get('session_history', []) if session_history else []

def update_session_history(session_id, user_input, bot_response):
    # Retrieve session history for the specified session ID from the session_history collection
    session_history = session_history_collection.find_one({'session_id': session_id})
    session_history = session_history.get('session_history', []) if session_history else []
    session_history.append({'user_input': user_input, 'bot_response': bot_response})

    # Update or insert session history in the session_history collection
    session_history_collection.update_one({'session_id': session_id}, {'$set': {'session_history': session_history}}, upsert=True)
    
@app.route('/delete_chat_session/<session_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_chat_session(session_id):
    try:
        # Delete the chat session with the given session_id
        # Perform necessary database operations here
        active_chat_sessions_collection.delete_one({'session_id': int(session_id)})
        chat_sessions_collection.delete_one({'session_id': int(session_id)})

        return jsonify({'success': True}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500`

I added debugging and logs to see what's happening, and I noticed that:

Despite the sessions working, and the databases remaining null, the messages are being stored in chat_messages??! (the chat_sessions() doesn't include the chat_messages collection for storing any data, it uses session_messages and session_history)

The session_id is being passed to the code in the 'GET' method only.

Seemingly that the main code is working perfectly fine, i expected the sessions to work perfectly as well, and not getting the session_id associated with the conversation's inputs and outputs had me at a very serious road block.

There are no errors in my code, you can start a new session and converse normally, but no data is being stored.


